# Starting ddd with remote gdbserver

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver, ddd-debugger

I'm debugging a program that runs on a remote target using ddd ( the remote gdbserver is running on localhost over port 1234 for example, but still acts as remote).

I know you can connect to the gdbserver by opening ddd, then calling `target remote localhost:1234` on the gdb command line of ddd, as described in:
http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html#Remote%20Program

However, I hate having to call the `target remote localhost:1234` command every time I open ddd, and I'd like to set it to connect to the gdbserver automatically with an alias. I tried running `ddd --rhost localhost:1234 program`, but once ddd launches a window pops stating that "GDB could not be started", and in the shell written:

> sh: 1: exec: localhost:1234: not found

Anyone knows how can I attach to the remote gdbserver right on launch?

Tnx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choose one of:

1. `ddd --eval-command="target remote localhost:1234"`
2. put `target remote localhost:1234` into a file and use `--command`
   to execute it
3. put `target remote localhost:1234` into your `.gdbinit`