# Attaching "ddd" to a process running on a remote machine

Tags: c++, c, gdb, remote-server

There is a running process on remote machine which we call "compute machine", where regular login are disabled. How do I attach the debugger [gdb/ddd] to the process running on remote machine [compute machine]. 'Attach Process' on ddd GUI cannot see the PID of the process running on remote machine.

Comment: Is your "ddd" related to "Domain driven design"?

Comment: Have you read [20 Debugging Remote Programs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html), though I am not sure this is feasible in your situation.

Comment: You need to run the gdb server on the remote machine. Say `man gdbserver`. To use with `ddd`, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096506/starting-ddd-with-remote-gdbserver).

Comment: For combination with username/password access, I'm trying to combine the approach given by n.m. with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24013387/connect-gdb-client-through-terminal-server-with-authentication). Not sure if it works yet. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

GDB is not aware of what append in your "compute machine" if you don't use `gdbserver`
But, if you use a ARM based board as "compute machine" you can give a try at OpenOCD (+GDB) and its RTOS awarness.